# Communicating with ViewModel from MainView

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and still trying to get a grasp on it so let me know if I'm setting this up wrong. What I have is a UserControl with a ListView in it. I populate this ListView with data from the ViewModel then add the control to my MainView. On my MainView I have a button that I want to use to add an item to the ListView. Here is what I have:

Model

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _itemCollection;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item("One"),
            new Item("Two"),
            new Item("Three"),
            new Item("Four"),
            new Item("Five"),
            new Item("Six"),
            new Item("Seven")
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemCollection");
        }
    }
}
```

View (XAML)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainContentControl.Content = new ListControl();
    }

    private void Button_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

MainWindow (XAML)

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Add" Click="Button_Add" />

        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="mainContentControl" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, from what I understand, I should be able to just an item to ItemCollection and it will be updated in the view. How do I do this from the Button_Add event?

Again, if I'm doing this all wrong let me know and point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not interact directly with the controls.

What you need to do is define a Command (a class that implements the ICommand-interface) and define this command on your ViewModel.

Then you bind the Button's command property to this property of the ViewModel. In the ViewModel you can then execute the command and add an item directly to your list (and thus the listview will get updated through the automatic databinding).

This link should provide more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec11

Comment: Thats what I thought but I wasn't sure. I spent some time researching ICommand and was able to get it working. Thanks!